# (Kiss)XML xpath and default namespace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xpath, kissxml

I am working on an iPhone project that needs to parse some xml. The xml may or may not include a default namespace. I need to know how to parse the xml in case it uses a default namespace. As I need to both read an write xml, I'm leaning towards using KissXML, but I'm open for suggestions.

This is my code:

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource:@"bookstore" ofType:@"xml"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:content options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *results = [theDocument nodesForXPath:@"//book" error:nil];
NSLog(@"%d", [results count]);
```

It works as expected on this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

But when the xml has a namespace, like this, it stops working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore xmlns="[INSERT RANDOM NAMESPACE]">
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Of course, I could just preprocess the string and remove the xmlns, though that feels like a sort of ugly hack. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Clean Way: Querying for the Namespace

You can use two XPath queries, one to fetch the namespace, then register it; as second query use the one you already have including namespaces. I can only help you with the query, but it seems you're quite familiar with namespaces and how to register them in the KissXML framework:

```
namespace-uri(/*)
```

This expression fetches all child nodes starting at the document root, which is per XML definition a single root element, and returns it's namespace uri.

## The Ugly Way: Only Testing for Local Name

It seems KissXML only supports XPath 1.0. With this less-capable language version, you need to use wildcard selectors at each axis step and compare the local name (without namespace prefix) inside the predicate:

```
//*[local-name(.) = 'book']
```

Starting from XPath 2.0, you could query using the namespace wildcard, which is much shorter:

```
//*:book
```

Comment: Countless hours of googling, researching, hair-pulling... I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/issues/20#issuecomment-7998639) KissXML implements "correct" behaviour while NSXML doesn't.  Which doesn't exactly help.  There is a [proposed fix for this](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/pull/27) waiting to be merged. [edit] 11/2021 - *still* waiting to be merged!

Expanding on the accepted answer's first proposed solution the workaround I [found](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/issues/21#issuecomment-13346952) was to rename the default namespace and then use that prefix in my XPath queries.  Something like:

```
    DDXMLNode *defaultNamespace = [document.rootElement namespaceForPrefix:@""];
    defaultNamespace.name = @"default";
    NSArray *xmlNodes = [[document rootElement] nodesForXPath:@"//default:foo/default:bar" error:nil];
```

This seems cleaner to me than textual processing of the file.  You could of course check and handle namespace collisions but the above should work in most simple cases.