# Xpath path not working

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I'm trying to get an element and its siblings via XpathNavigator.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_6_5_5.dtd'>
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='6.5' maintenanceversion='5.0'>
    <item name='Keywords'><text/></item>
    <item name='Version'><number>1</number></item>
    <item name='UPDATEDISTRIBUTION'><text>1</text></item>
    <item name='$FILE' summary='true' sign='true' seal='true'>
        <object>
            <file hosttype='cdstorage' compression='none' flags='storedindoc' name='STG08828'>
                <created><datetime>20110119T230442,22+01</datetime></created>
            </file>
        </object>
    </item>
</document>
```

I want to navigate to the file-element, with the following XPath:

```
//item/name/object/file[@name='STG08828']
```

Why this path is wrong?

EDIT: Thanks for the hint with my "name"-mistake.

When I try to run it, I get nothing.

```
XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
// select the file Element
String query = "//file[@name='" + name + "']";
XmlNodeList fileElement = rootNode.SelectNodes(query);
```

Comment: `//item/name` is an attribute not an element. Try changing the xpath to `//item/object/file[@name='STG08828']`

Comment: Are you sure they're the same case (the two `name` values) as XSLT is case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the xml file which i pasted above. There are only more item-elements in it.

Comment: I forgot to copy the DOCTYPE element... updated my post.

Comment: I know I'm clutching at strws, but are you sure that `name` (the variable that is used in `String query = "//file[@name='" + name + "']";`) is the same case and doesn't have any white-space in it?

Comment: Your XML contains namespaces. It seems you did not register and use them.

Comment: @freefaller yes I'm sure. The output is "//file[@name='STG08828']"

Comment: @JensErat How do I use them? I will search.

Comment: OK, @float, I'm just trying to remove obvious possibilities.  I think Jens is on the right track with the namespacing. Look at the `XmlNamespaceManager` class

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that you try to help me :-) I will have a look.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore namespaces? I found how to Add the Namespace, but now the XML Reader which im forced to use requires the dtd. But actually I'm not validating something with the dtd or the namespace.

Comment: For example, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315846/kissxml-xpath-and-default-namespace/17338847#17338847). As far as I know C# only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. How could I add the missing dtd to the XmlDocument, so that I would user the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
//item/object/file[@name='STG08828']
```

Or maybe just:

```
//file[@name='STG08828']
```

Comment: You are right, but when I try to get it, nothing is selected... I update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing your names space for xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl'

Example:

```
XNamespace myMs = "http://www.lotus.com/dxl";
```